# Calculate difference sequentially on a SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have to develop a report in SSRS in which I have to display, between other info, the difference between 2 columns. The problem stands in the case that some sequential rows are connected to each other and the difference must be subtracted from the previous row. The amount of rows that are connected with each other can hardly be more than 5. Explained:

```
col1|   col2|   PK| Amount| Paid|   Remaining
-------------------------------------------------  
data|   data|    1|   100|    20|   80
data|   data|    1|   100|    40|   40    
data|   data|    1|   100|    10|   30    
data|   data|    2|   200|   150|   50    
data|   data|    2|   200|    50|    0
```

Is there any way to do this with SSRS? I have searched about the usage of the Previous function but couldn't be used for this case, a variable, but a global one does not suit my case, and a group variable I do not have a clear idea on how to use it. The dataset comes from a SQL query. Can anyone help me on this case? The report has a very complicated query behind and I want to change it only if it is really necessary.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty straightforward way to handle this.  Just add PK as a parent group to your current detail rows, then go ahead and delete the generated column.  This will allow you to put the Remaining number in terms of the original amount less the running total of payments within that PK group:

`=Fields!Amount.Value - RunningValue(Fields!Paid.Value,Sum,"PK")`